# Not getting value in jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I have a hidden field

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SchedulingProfileDetails.Id)
```

and I am trying to get the value of the hidden field in a jquery function

```
var id = $('#SchedulingProfileDetails_Id').val();
```

But I am getting the value as null. Why's that can somebody help?

My generated HTML

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="SchedulingProfileDetails_Id" name="SchedulingProfileDetails.Id" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Comment: check the generated html and see what is its id

Comment: same SchedulingProfileDetails_Id

Comment: is there a <input id="SchedulingProfileDetails_Id"/> in your html?

Comment: put the code of rendered html

Comment: val() is only for input tags not for any other types use text() instead.

Comment: A hidden field is an input tag, I have certainly used val() for hidden fields in the past.

Comment: `$(':hidden[id*="SchedulingProfileDetails"]').val();` try this.

Comment: @Jai it give undefined at debug time earliar i was getting null

Comment: see the first comment by Arun.

Comment: You don't have any value in you hidden field. What did you expect actually?

Comment: I EXPECTED A 0 THERE INITIALLY WHICH WILL KEEP ON CHANGING

Comment: i am able to get value $('#SchedulingProfileDetails_Id').val();  if no values then it will be null

Comment: it could be some other issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SchedulingProfileDetails.Id)` contains some `Id`.

Also I'm guessing you are passing that id from controller's method. If not make sure to do it.

So in controller

```
public ActionResult foo()
{
   var model = new Vm//this should be your model of the view
   {
       Id = //assign the value, and make sure it is not null, if it is you'll see the val you are mentioning as null
       //assign some other stuff if you want
   }
   return View(Vm);
}
```

Now in view, you can access the val as:

```
var id = $('#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SchedulingProfileDetails.Id)').val();//check the syntax i'm not sure if you need # or not,I haven't checked it on the code
```

This should work.

There is built in [Html.IdFor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) that will extract the id for you, and you don't have to worry about the id that is being generated.